# How to add cellClick or Rowclick in Devexpress Gantt?

Tags: devexpress

```
<dx:ASPxGantt ID="Gantt" runat="server" Height="700" Width="100%" >
   <SettingsTaskList Width="40%">
        <Columns>
<dx:GanttTextColumn FieldName="FleetNo" Caption="Fleet No" Width="100" />
  </Columns>
    </SettingsTaskList>
</dx:ASPxGantt>
```

Is there any option toadd cellClick or Rowclick in Devexpress Gantt?

Comment: Please visit https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/